# Convergence/Divergence of $\log n/\log(\log n)$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to determine if the sum converges absolutely, conditionally or diverges.

$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{\log n}{\log(\log n)}$$

I started with the limit comparison test, but couldn't find a suitable $b_n$.

What am I missing?

Comment: You've got $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ but in the expression that follows that I don't see any "$n$". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Oops. I meant to use n as the variable. I'm a bit burnt out at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

If a series $\sum_n a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=0$.

Is it true that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}{\log \log n} =0 $?

Comment: It goes to infinity, and therefore would diverge...I think.

Comment: Indeed, that's it.

Comment: Thanks! I seem to have a penchant for over-complicating simple problems.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go is [Cauchy condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) which is to study the equivalent series

> $$ \ln(2)\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{2^nn}{\ln(n \ln 2)} .$$

Comment: @Dr.MV: Yes, thanks for the comment. I appreciate it.

Comment: My pleasure.  I hope you don't mind my taking care of it.  Great answer by the way!

Comment: @Dr.MV: of course I do not mind. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the Comparison Test$$\log n\lt n\implies\log\log n\lt\log n\implies1\lt\dfrac{\log n}{\log\log n}$$